# d3.select by namespaced attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

This almost does it for my case:

`d3.select('g[id^="layer"]')`

But it's just not bulletproof. I need to be able to do:

`d3.select('g[inkscape:groupmode="layer"]')`

This produces an invalid selector error. Doesn't make a difference whether I add `inkscape` to `d3.namespaces` or not.

P.s. I'm working on an Inkscape edited SVG, I need to be able to render it in browser DOM, manipulate it and export it back to an SVG with all "metadata" in namespaced attributes intact.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up filtering using [Element.getAttributeNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttributeNS).

```
// Set namespace
d3.namespaces.inkscape = 'http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape'

// Filter selection
d3.select('#my_svg').selectAll('g').filter(function (d, i) {
    return this.getAttributeNS(d3.namespaces.inkscape, 'groupmode') === 'layer'
})
```

Does anyone know of a more D3-like way of doing it?

Comment: Did you ever find a better/proper/more d3 way of doing this? I have the same sort of problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514047/)

Comment: Sorry, I did not. I haven't used D3 since so I'm not up to date with it anymore.

Comment: I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808801/d3-select-by-namespaced-attribute), which solved the issue for me. Prefix the 'inkscape' namespace with colon (:).

Comment: @claudejoliat, your link merely points back to this question. Is there more discussion of this somewhere, as just prefixing a colon to the namespace isn't working for me?