# d3.select on inkscape:label="foo"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, inkscape

I'm trying to select a layer by its `inkscape:label` property to be able to show/hide the layer on a website.

```
function hideFOO() {
    if(d3.select("#hideFOO:checked").node()){
        d3.select("#layer11").attr("visibility", "hidden");
    } else {
        d3.select("#layer11").attr("visibility", "visible");        
    }
}
```

The SVG is;

```
<g
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer11"
     inkscape:label="foo"
     style="display:inline"> ...
```

That works just fine - but I'd like to be able to specify the `inkscape:label` as the layer ID's are not the same across multiple SVG's, but the layer names are.

When I try something like;
`d3.select(":inkscape:label='foo'").attr("visibility", "hidden");` I just get told; `SyntaxError: ':inkscape:label='foo'' is not a valid selector`

or `d3.select("$('g[inkscape:label="foo"]')").attr("visibility", "hidden");` which tells me `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` though all my ')' are closed?!

Based on a solution below - I also tried with `d3.select('g[inkscape\\:label = "foo"]').attr("visibility", "hidden");` but it's not hiding the layer either - when playing in the dev console for the browser it appears the `d3.select` isn't matching on the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After endless playing with commands I've finally somehow stumbled across this solution which appears to work as expected, and does not need me to specify any namespaces or the like.

```
function hideFOO() {
    if(d3.select("#hideFOO:checked").node()){
        d3.select("g[*|label='foo']").attr("visibility", "hidden");
    } else {
        d3.select("g[*|label='foo']").attr("visibility", "visible");        
    }
}
```

I've tried to declare the namespace when the `svg` is loaded and it shows registered in the query console but if I try and specify `inkscape|label` it just complains about an invalid selector... I guess the only issue of using `*|label` is if ever there's something else in a separate namespace identifying with `label` it will cause problems.

If anyone can suggest how to get it working as `inkscape|label='foo'` please comment below.

I have also just found that older versions of IE (11) do not like this and won't hide or show the layers as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can turn the visibility to hidden using CSS:

The idea is that you need to use inkscape's namespace

```css
/*declare the prefix for the namespace*/
@namespace ink "http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape";

/*escape the colon : or use the pipe |*/
[inkscape\:label="foo"], [ink|label="foo"] {
/*visibility:hidden*/
fill:red;}

svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg>
  <g
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer11"
     inkscape:label="foo"
     style="display:inline">
    <rect width="100" height="50"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Please read this article about [XML Namespaces in CSS](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/extras/ch03-namespaces.html), a [Using SVG with CSS3 and HTML5](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920037972.do) supplementary Material

And this is how you can do it with javascript (You can’t use namespace prefixes in the `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` methods ):

```js
let g = document.querySelector('g[inkscape\\:label = "foo"]')
 //g.style.visibility = "hidden"
 g.style.fill = "red"
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg>
  <g
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer11"
     inkscape:label="foo"
     style="display:inline">
    <rect width="100" height="50"/>
  </g>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Have just tried with `d3.select('g[inkscape\\:label = "foo"]').attr("visibility", "hidden");` but it's not hiding the layer. I suspect I've not understood something. I presumed (maybe wrongly) doing it this way would mean I didn't need to worry about declaring the namespace?

Comment: Maybe you should try to set `visibility:hidden`  for the `style` atttribute

Comment: this did not fix the problem at all sorry.

Comment: Stumbled onto this thread after a lot of head scratching with this one myself. For me, escaping the colon with \: in CSS works and double escaping with \\: in jQuery works too. The namespace information in this post is useful and the sample code works. This shouldn't have been voted down, in my opinion.

The spaces surrounding the equal sign in the `label = "foo"` string should be removed though. Perhaps that's the issue OP was having.